# calling method without passing argument

Tags: ruby, ldap, openldap

This is my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ldap'

class LdapUser
    def create_connection
       ldap = Net::LDAP.new
       ldap.host = 'localhost'
       ldap.port = 389
       puts "****** Conncection result ********"
       puts ldap.get_operation_result 
       return ldap
   end

  # only admin can authenticate
  def authenticate(ldap)
       ldap.authenticate "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com",'123'  
  end
user = LdapUser.new
ldap=user.create_connection
user.authenticate(ldap)
```

I want to call `authenticate` with the object without passing `ldap` as argument.

Is there any way to do that? Is there any way that makes the code more productive and efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class LdapUser
  def ldap
    return @ldap if @ldap
    create_connection
  end

  # only admin can authenticate
  def authenticate
    ldap.authenticate "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com",'123'  
  end

  private

  def create_connection
    @ldap = Net::LDAP.new
    @ldap.host = 'localhost'
    @ldap.port = 389
    puts "****** Conncection result ********"
    puts @ldap.get_operation_result 
    @ldap
  end
end

user = LdapUser.new
user.authenticate
```

Comment: This solution has a flaw: `create_connection` must be called in advance. The proper way would be to put lazy initialization inside getter `def ldap; return @ldap if @ldap; @ldap = Net::LDAP.new; ...`. That way the call to authenticate will succeed in any case.

Comment: Agree with you @mudasobwa. I have updated the answer accordingly.